# Jquery $.ajax returning undefined jqXHR in error handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: reply_url,
        data: reply_data,            
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
          alert(jqXHR.status);
        }
      });
```

And I'm getting the following error when the server returns 500:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

What are the cases where jqXHR could be undefined?

PS: I'm using Jquery v1.8.3

EDIT:

I noticed that this happens only in Ajax calls to my Ruby on Rails application. Ajax calls to another domains returns jqXHR as exptected.

Comment: have you tried:  ``error: function(xhr, statusText, err) { xhr.status}``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad you actually wrote the same, only without `alert()`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I just tried, I got the same result.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I tested on Chrome 36 and Firefox 31.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here: **http://jsbin.com/rajusolu/1/edit?js,output**

your request function does actually work.... (I tested it also with jQuery 1.8.3 and works fine). If you want to try that link remember to select "Add library" > "jQuery".

If you see that error then is something related to some other part of your code, because the snippet you provided works fine.

Comment: The application JS is pretty extensive. Is it possible that some code elsewhere is intercepting the returned jqXHR object and setting it to undefined before the error handler?

Comment: I don't really know, I can't tell what's wrong without the code.